# How to get prediction label along with percentage

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction, transfer-learning

I am using transfer learning to retrain VGG16 model on Fruits360 dataset using keras. I have already trained the model and generated the model.h5 file. Now, to test the model I trained I wrote a separate code as shown below and loaded the model.h5 file and the input image and predicted using model.predict() function. I got an array of predicted values as output, but I am not able to get the label for the output.
How do I also get the labels after predicting?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.models import load_model
import os 

my_list = os.listdir('./fruits-360/Training')
labels = sorted(my_list)
#print(len(labels))

saved_model = load_model("output.h5")
# load an image from file
image = load_img('apple.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
# convert the image pixels to a numpy array
image = img_to_array(image)
# reshape data for the model
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
# prepare the image for the VGG model
image = preprocess_input(image)
# predict the probability across all output classes
yhat = saved_model.predict(image)

print(yhat)
```

The output that I got from this:

```
[[7.17755854e-02 1.64420519e-04 7.11962930e-04 1.09639345e-03
  3.65487649e-03 1.30461820e-03 1.71189080e-03 8.44106398e-05
  2.32845647e-04 2.93225341e-04 5.51751134e-09 8.36079926e-06
  2.45124284e-07 4.89534505e-05 3.62677121e-04 3.77899994e-07
  1.04390840e-09 2.77215719e-07 1.48338046e-07 1.58574392e-06
  1.85948572e-08 2.35122825e-05 1.40991315e-05 1.53142121e-09
  4.20618314e-08 9.00860164e-10 8.37871852e-08 1.38314470e-04
  2.33362043e-05 1.02217612e-07 1.56784572e-05 1.45486838e-05
  1.35744230e-07 7.53441327e-07 8.10141572e-08 9.25831589e-09
  1.17044747e-05 7.80909737e-09 1.17813433e-05 1.39052809e-05
  1.33823562e-06 8.83602411e-07 5.22362086e-07 3.12003103e-04
  3.63733534e-07 3.09960592e-06 7.83494880e-10 2.16209537e-06
  1.09540458e-07 1.00488634e-07 5.04332002e-06 3.11387431e-08
  1.43967145e-06 3.70907003e-08 9.72185060e-02 7.17791181e-07
  8.50022047e-07 1.09006250e-11 8.06401147e-07 2.94776954e-04
  1.42594319e-04 6.57663213e-06 2.22632690e-09 1.33982932e-04
  7.27764191e-03 1.76724559e-03 4.58840788e-07 2.83163081e-05
  1.27739793e-06 1.51839274e-07 6.35151446e-01 1.49872008e-04
  1.69212143e-07 6.46130411e-06 8.09798095e-09 1.33023859e-04
  3.11768084e-10 6.82332274e-03 2.72009001e-05 1.36803810e-05
  3.21909931e-04 2.18727801e-05 4.89347076e-06 1.65353231e-05
  8.18530396e-02 2.71601088e-08 3.78919160e-03 1.93472511e-06
  2.28390039e-04 9.45829204e-04 8.07484355e-08 2.39097773e-07
  3.94911304e-08 6.42228715e-10 1.27851049e-10 2.42364536e-06
  6.91388919e-08 5.50304435e-07 5.60582407e-08 6.93544493e-08
  2.04468861e-07 1.82402204e-07 1.29191315e-08 1.40132336e-03
  7.21434930e-08 1.26103216e-04 7.80344158e-02 6.98078452e-07
  6.39117275e-07 4.86231899e-09 6.67545173e-05 1.98491052e-05
  3.82679382e-08 4.00836188e-06 1.76605427e-05 5.99655250e-05
  1.41588691e-06 6.29748298e-09 1.60603679e-03 2.18801666e-04
  1.52924549e-05 2.39897645e-07 5.80409534e-08 1.40595137e-06
  4.33732907e-07 9.40148311e-06 6.87087507e-08 9.42246814e-08
  4.06775257e-07 1.12163532e-08 8.79949056e-08]]
```

I tried a lot of different options that were answered in other questions regarding the same but I was not able to find out any solution to this. ***Can anyone help?***
*If you want I can also provide the retraining code for reference.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So the 'saved_model' provides only feature extraction while you want 'saved_model' returns feature extraction + final probabilities?

Comment: I want it to return the probability and label of the fruit/vegetable that is in the image.

Comment: what does saved_model return when you call predict?

Comment: Just the probabilites, as shown in output

Comment: if the outputs are probabilities simply np.argmax(yhat, axis=1) gives you the predicted label

Comment: Using this gave me [70] as output.

Comment: you got the numeric id of the label

Comment: How can I get the label from numeric id, I used flow_from_directory function while retraining. So, its just alphabetical order of the classes or anything else?

Comment: Also, among these probabilities as I have shown in the output, which is the probability of the predicted label. Can you help with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the labels  from the training dataset as:

```
    class_names = your_train_ds.class_names
    labels = (v_datagen.class_indices)
    # this returns python dictionary in order of label_name:index
    
    # We need to switch this order to index:label_name, 
    # so that we can access the label name using the index as key

    labels = dict((val,ky) for ky,val in labels.items())
```

Now, get the prediction index as mentioned in the comments

```
    pred_ind = np.argmax(yhat, axis=1)
    print(labels[pred_ind])
```